# How Do I fix "cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type" error?

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I don't know much about lambda expressions, I'm currently getting the title error and also "cannot implicitly convert int to bool", here is my code:

```
var store = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            var customerCloseEvents = events.Where(x =>
            {
                var cacheKey = $"{customer.City}:{x.City}";
                if (store.ContainsKey(cacheKey))
                {
                    return store[cacheKey];
                }
                else
                {
                    var distance = GetDistance(customer.City, x.City);
                    store.Add(cacheKey, distance);
                    return distance;
                }
            }).Take(15).ToList();
```

The event has just two properties, city and name.

Comment: Do in two steps.  First add new values to store.  Then query store to get all values.  Other choice is not to use linq.  The q in linq is query.  linq is not meant to change items, only to retrieve.

Comment: It complains about `cannot implicitly convert int to bool` due to `.Where` expects `Func<TSource, bool>`, the function that returns bool, true for elements that met the condition, and you are returning a `distance`. Try using `.ForEach` first to populate the store, and then to use `OrderBy` (using dict data) with `Take`.